# Can I Create a Controller instance manually, then run it as a user?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

For example, from a controller I want to do something like this:

```
var controller = new SomeController(); //different controller
//as of now, the controller.User is null, I want to set it
controller.DoSomething();
```

I want to set the User as it uses the roles to decide what to do here.  I would prefer to leave all the role handling in that controller (not my code).   Is there any way to set the User?  Or possibly run it as the same user as I am calling this from another controller in the same MVC project?

EDIT: My solution after Sergey's help, in my Controller BaseClass:

```
public T RunControllerAsCurrentUser<T>(T controller, RouteData routeData = null) where T : ControllerBase
{
    var newContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), routeData ?? new RouteData(), controller);
    controller.ControllerContext = newContext;
    return controller;
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var someController = RunControllerAsCurrentUser(new Some.NameSpace.SomeController());
var result = someController.SomeAction();
```

Comment: Well, this one will return `ActionResult`. And even if you set `User`, then it might not execute correclty returned `ActionResult`. As another solutuin, you can create a stub HttpContext, with correct url for this controller, and execute it. It will fill HttpContext that will be bounded to StringBuilder and then you can get your rendered html

Comment: @Sergey, can you expand on this a bit?  I don't even need to get the rendered Html, just that the method ran.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends what your method is using. If you just need to execute method then you can try something like that:

```
var factory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IControllerFactory>() ?? new DefaultControllerFactory();
TestController controller = factory.CreateController(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext, "Test") as TestController;

RouteData route = new RouteData();
route.Values.Add("action", "Test"); // ActionName, but it not required

ControllerContext newContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), route, controller);
controller.ControllerContext = newContext;
ActionResult result = controller.Test();
```

This approach will do some basic controller initialization, but if your method uses some parameters, or request specific data, then it might require specifying them in `RouteData.Values`.

Try this approach and tell in comments if it works for you or not.

Comment: I believe this would work, but I run into a problem with Areas.  I have two same named controllers, but in different areas.  So "TestController controller = factory.CreateController(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext, "Test") as TestController;" gives me a null since it is the wrong "TestController" - is there any way to specify an area?   I tried just doing controller = var factory.CreateController(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext, "Test"); and this gave me a non-null controller, just the wrong one...

Comment: If you are not using any `IoC` container, then you can just create it manually. As Areas are just classes in own namespace, so you can create it like this - `TestController controller = SomeRoot.MvcUI.Areas.MyArea.Controllers.TestController`

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use HttpContext.User, as:

```
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrentUser(), new String[0] /*roles*/);
```