# Get controller by controller name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, controller

How can I get Controller (System.Web.Mvc? if I have controller name.

I get controller name by: `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];`

I have a controller name in string.

Comment: What do you mean _How can I get Controller_? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need controller class from System.Web.Mvc

Comment: Do you mean you want to initialize a new instance of that controller class? (not clear what your trying to do, and why)

Comment: I need to pass my controller which has been invoked the action. I'm in the 3rd class

Comment: You already have it - `var controller = this.ControllerContext.Controller;`

Comment: I'm in the 3rd (service) and I don't have access to controllercontext

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133516/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-cieja).

Comment: YOur answer is probably here and I think it is an exact duplicate of what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865598/asp-net-mvc-3-get-the-current-controller-instance-not-just-name

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433972/can-i-create-a-controller-instance-manually-then-run-it-as-a-user) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
string controllerName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

Comment: How can I parse it to the System.Web.Mvc?

Comment: you want to call controller action from another class?

Comment: I need pass my controller class

Answer (score 0):

You can use refelection, If your controller is within the assembly you just need a class name, otherwise you need a fully qualified name (namespace and assembly).

> Type t = Type.GetType("NameOfController"); 
>   var  c =
>   Activator.CreateInstance(t);